Books Defending Caste and Untouchability
It is obvious that today's historians never place themselves in the shoes of past people and have a very one-sided and biased view of history looking at an individual over a societal level. I am curious if there is any book that defends Caste and Untouchability from a historical and religious perspective by looking at the situation ancient people had to face. New or old doesn't matter to me, but no neo-Hindu-type stuff. Preferably from a religious scholar or pundit of a well-established sampradaya.

I doubt whether this book is the answer to your question or not (since I haven't read it myself), but 'Marxvād aur Rāmarājya' might be what you are seeking. It's author Svami Karapatri was a well-renowned saint in Hindi belt in the 60s & 70s, who had formed an ultra-conservative Hindu far-right political party called the Akhil Bharatiya Ramarajya Parishad & had organised the 1966 anti-cow slaughter agitation in front of the Parliament & the subsequent rioting in Delhi.

@অনু more on the religious side and older, but thanks for commenting.

A book called VARṆA VIDYĀ : The Biological Basis of Varṇa Dharma, especially for Women and the Śūdra Varṇa written by Sinu Joseph published by Rare book society of India explains the science behind the spiritual path prescribed for women and the śūdra varṇa.More than 100 saṃskṛtam verses from smṛti-s (Manu, Yājñavalkya, Parāśara, etc.), the Bhagvad Gītā, Śrīmad Bhāgavatam, Upaniṣad-s and Tantra texts have been covered in this work, revealing their subtle meaning. Several published studies and modern scientific theories have also been included to ease the understanding of the present generation.
